# How to create DropShadow effect in QML with Qt6?

Tags: qt, qml, shadow, qt6

In **Qt5** this was easy with using [DropShadow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-dropshadow.html).
But in **Qt6** the module [QtGraphicalEffects is removed](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_6.0).

Is there any trick, workaround or maybe new way in **Qt6** to create drop shadow around some component?

Comment: Well, it's definitely not easy, but you can still write your own [ShaderEffects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-shadereffect.html) in Qt6. I'm pretty sure QtGraphicalEffects will come back in later releases, but for now you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Or you could do it with translucent images.

Comment: yea it looks like that is the way. I will try your suggestion and add it as answer if it works. Thank you

Comment: @user123445151156 can you please post example usage of ShaderEffects if you succeed creating Shadow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noticed yourself, `Qt Graphical Effects` is [removed (definitely)](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_6.0#Removed_Modules):

> The following modules are removed and not planned to be developed
> further.
>
> - Qt Graphical Effects
> - [...]

However, the `Qt Graphical Effects` is made compatible with the new `QRhi` (Qt Rendering Hardware Interface) used by Qt6. [[1]](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-78572)

Note that this doesn't mean it will be included in Qt 6 at a later stage. [[2]](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-85256)

Nevertheless, I expect it would be relatively easy to use `DropShadow` from the dev or Qt 5.15 branch of git.

Note that it is included as a [`Qt5 Compatibility API`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/graphicaleffects5.html) in Qt6.1: [DropShadow](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qml-qt5compat-graphicaleffects-dropshadow.html).

Comment: Now there is a new module [QtQuick.Effects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-effects-qmlmodule.html) since [Qt 6.5](https://www.qt.io/blog/a-short-guide-to-qt-quick-effects)

Comment: @danieltakeshi, you may consider adding an answer yourself explaining how it could be done in Qt 6.5 (and newer).

Answer (score 2):

[Qt6 DropShadow](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qml-qt5compat-graphicaleffects-dropshadow.html)

```
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects
DropShadow {}
```

Comment: any suggestions for `innershadow`?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `QtGraphicalEffects` module to Qt6 manually and then use `DropShadow` in your code.

Generally, to unofficially employ `QtGraphicalEffects` in Qt 6, do the following:

```
$ git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtgraphicaleffects.git
$ cd qtgraphicaleffects/
$ git checkout 59ab3e11433a5157aac0f3af7c0d7fe70a373373 & cd ..
$ ~/Qt/<VERSION>/gcc_64/bin/qmake qtgraphicaleffects
$ make
$ find qtgraphicaleffects/src/effects/ -maxdepth 1 -name \*.qml -exec cp {} qml/QtGraphicalEffects \;
$ cp -r qtgraphicaleffects/src/effects/private/ qml/QtGraphicalEffects
$ cp -r qml/QtGraphicalEffects ~/Qt/<VERSION>/gcc_64/qml/
```

This will obtain the module source code to the point where it wasn't yet completely removed from the repository. Then it is built and copied with the required files to the Qt installed directory.

So to use `DropShadow` component, add

```
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
```

You can also use the following components in your QML code:

- BrightnessContrast
- Colorize
- ColorOverlay
- ConicalGradient
- Desaturate
- Displace
- **DropShadow**
- FastBlur
- FastGlow
- GammaAdjust
- Glow
- HueSaturation
- LevelAdjust
- LinearGradient
- OpacityMask
- RadialGradient
- RectangularGlow
- ThresholdMask

Comment: If anyone can do that why did they removed it?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to 2D effects, get familiar with [MultiEffect](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-6.5/qml-qtquick-effects-multieffect.html). For the most common effects, such as blur or **drop shadow**, this should be the primary choice.
Avoid pulling in the legacy Qt Graphical Effects types from the Qt5Compat module.

Source: https://www.qt.io/blog/post-processing-effects-for-3d-in-qt-6.5

```js
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Effects

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello Shadow")

    Rectangle {
        id: sourceItem
        width: 100
        height: 100
        radius: 10
        y: 40
        x: 40
        color: "red"
    }

    MultiEffect {
        source: sourceItem
        anchors.fill: sourceItem
        shadowBlur: 1.0
        shadowEnabled: true
        shadowColor: "black"
        shadowVerticalOffset: 15
        shadowHorizontalOffset: 11
    }
```